# Monitoring aspnet core web app in kubernetes with App Metrics and Influxdb does not work

Tags: asp.net-core, kubernetes, grafana, influxdb

I am trying to monitor my aspnet core webapp in k8s with Grafana-Influxdb through App Metrics Template.

I have followed all the steps posted in [this article](https://dzone.com/articles/real-time-performance-monitoring-in-net-core-with) and the App metrics documentation. However, I cannot see any data coming from Influx-db.

Some of the things that I have already checked:

- The Influxdb datasource is correctly connected to Grafana
- /metrics  and /metrics-text are returning data
- I have checked the logs of Influx-db and seems like the pings are working

[httpd] xx.xxxx.xx.xx - - [07/Mar/2019:01:58:14 +0000] "GET /ping HTTP/1.1" 204 0 "-" "kube-probe/1.12" 77f046bd-407c-11e9-b1f0-a68c07c04186 54

The code to connect with Influxdb:

```
    var metrics = new MetricsBuilder()
        .Report.ToInfluxDb(options => {
            options.InfluxDb.BaseUri = new Uri("http://influxdb-influxdb.monitoring:8086");
            options.InfluxDb.Database = "appmetrics";
            options.InfluxDb.Consistenency = "consistency";          
            options.InfluxDb.RetentionPolicy = "rp";
            options.InfluxDb.CreateDataBaseIfNotExists = true;
            options.HttpPolicy.BackoffPeriod = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
            options.HttpPolicy.FailuresBeforeBackoff = 5;
            options.HttpPolicy.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
            options.MetricsOutputFormatter = new MetricsInfluxDbLineProtocolOutputFormatter();                
            options.FlushInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);
        })
        .Build();

        services.AddMemoryCache();
        services.AddMetrics(metrics);
```

Comment: For having "followed all the steps" in the article, your startup configuration looks virtually nothing like the articles. I haven't personally set this up myself, but perhaps the issue is in something you changed. As one example. there seems to be some calls that are necessary in `Configure` as well, which you haven't posted here: `app.UseMetrics` and `app.UseMetricsReporting`. Did you add those?

Comment: What I did to make to make it work was to follow the demo AspNetCore2.Api.Reservoirs in this repository https://github.com/AppMetrics/Samples.V2. There are plenty of options to configure the Metrics and all the previous did not work for me

Answer (score 0):

The solution was provided by the [Javier Hertfelder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/732537/javier-hertfelder) in the comments:

> What I did to make to make it work was to follow the demo `AspNetCore2.Api.Reservoirs` in this repository [github.com/AppMetrics/Samples.V2](https://github.com/AppMetrics/Samples.V2) There are plenty of options to configure the Metrics and all the previous did not work for me